# Grouping the date columns in week range

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle10g, netezza

i have a table and the columns like

```
Start_date timestamp,
end_date   timestamp,
id number,
cost number(10,2).
```

And the data which i inserted into the table 'll be like this

```
1,'2013-02-03 00:00:00','2013-02-03 00:00:00',75*0.06
1,'2013-02-04 00:00:00','2013-02-04 00:00:00',75*0.06
1,'2013-02-05 00:00:00','2013-02-05 00:00:00',75*0.06
1,'2013-02-06 00:00:00','2013-02-06 00:00:00',75*0.06
1,'2013-02-07 00:00:00','2013-02-07 00:00:00',75*0.06
1,'2013-02-08 00:00:00','2013-02-08 00:00:00',75*0.06
1,'2013-02-09 00:00:00','2013-02-09 00:00:00',75*0.06
```

and now i want to group the columns `Start_date` and `end_date` by Sunday to Saturday.

can you please help me on this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `week(start_date)` and `week(end_date)` gives you week number; from there you can group

Comment: @Dileep - Add some sample data and desired output. I personally do not understand what does it mean group by Sun to Sat... You can order by dates or week numbers or days etc...

Comment: @DoSparKot when i Tried like this select week(start_date),week(end_date) from table1; it is throwing error

Comment: @Art sample data 'll be like this 1,'2012-12-23 00:00:00','2012-12-23 00:00:00',null,null,343*0.06

Comment: update the post with table schema and sample data. use `show create table tablename`

Comment: One row of sample data and no expected output doesn't help us much.  How do you group by two different columns?  Particularly when those two columns fall in different weeks?

Comment: @Dileep - please post your expected answer too

Comment: @Dileep- Question is bit difficult to understand. I created one useful query. But its not fully correct. I still have confusion in your question, especially in the " i want to group the columns Start_date and end_date" part . Please add expected result too so i can tell you correct query.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I can offer you as your question is impossible to understand as well as that sample you provided. ISO week table for 2013:

```
SELECT start_date  -- 1/1/2013 --
 , TRUNC(start_date, 'iw')                  wk_starts  
 , TRUNC(start_date, 'iw') + 7 - 1/86400    wk_ends
 , TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (start_date, 'IW'))   ISO_wk#_iw  
 , TO_CHAR(start_date, 'DAY')               wk_day
FROM
 (
  SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YEAR')-1 + LEVEL AS start_date
   FROM dual
 CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 
 (
  SELECT TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, 12), 'Y')-TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'Y') "Num of Days in 2013"   
    FROM dual
 )
)
/

START_DATE    WK_STARTS    WK_ENDS            ISO_WK#   WK_DAY
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1/1/2013    12/31/2012    1/6/2013 11:59:59 PM    1    TUESDAY  
1/2/2013    12/31/2012    1/6/2013 11:59:59 PM    1    WEDNESDAY
.....
1/7/2013    1/7/2013    1/13/2013 11:59:59 PM    2    MONDAY   
1/8/2013    1/7/2013    1/13/2013 11:59:59 PM    2    TUESDAY
.....
```

You can add any other formats for your date and order by it I guess...

Comment: the problem with query is i can't use Trunc because i am using Netezza DB

Comment: @Dileep - What can you use? ROUND() may work... If TRUNC() is the problem then you need to find equivalent in Netezza. I never heard of it. You have Oracle tags in your question, so, I assumed Oracle query would help, give some idea...

Comment: most of the oracle functions ll use, but we c't use some of those like TRUNC,Level,etc..

Comment: i need the exact o/p which u have provided, but when i tried ur query with the respective changes in Netezza it's throwing error found "START_DATE" (at char 130) expecting `USING' or `')'' or `',''

Comment: @Dileep - very sorry, cannot help you with Netezza... I used LEVEL only to build table on the fly. You do not need to use that-you already have table with data. Try finding equivalents to Oracle TRUNC/ROUND functions in Netezza.